# How to remove formatting in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have pasted some code that looks like this:

```
Dto = new MyDto()
       {
           SessionId = sessionId.ToString(),
           UserName = username,
           License = allocateLicense
        },
```

but the pasted version looks like:

```
Dto = new MyDto
       ()
       {
           SessionId = 
              sessionId.
              ToString(),
           UserName =
              username,
           License = 
              allocateLicense
        },
```

I tried control-z (undo) and sometimes with simple pieces of code it reformats correctly but for other code it stays as above with line breaks.

So is there a way I can select the pasted code and reformat it so that the additional line breaks are removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is automatic formatting on paste you can of course disable it. If it's the other way around you can do the same as well..

Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting

appropriately set **Automatically format on paste**

Answer (score 0):

This happens often when you copy code from PDF files or web pages.
I usually remove the unwanted formatting by pasting the code on a plain-text editor like notepad, then from notepad over to Visual Studio.